# Is there a way to reverse the ordering of .Resources?

Tags: hugo

I have a page on my website where I show some photos I have taken. You can see it at [tomgamon.com/photos](https://tomgamon.com/photos).

The file structure for the page is like so.

```
content
└── photos
    ├── 2021-05-01.jpg
    ├── 2021-10-01.jpg
    ├── 2021-12-01.jpg
    └── _index.md
```

The photos page has a layout which includes this following snippet which iterates over the photos in the folder and renders them.

```
      {{ with .Resources.ByType "image" }}
        {{ range . }}
          {{ $imageMed := .Resize "600x webp photo q100" }}
          {{ $imageSml := .Resize "350x webp photo q100" }}
          <img class="photo" srcset="{{ $imageMed.RelPermalink }} 600w,{{ $imageSml.RelPermalink }} 350w" src="{{ $imageMed.RelPermalink }}" loading="lazy" sizes="(min-width: 800px) 600px, 100vw">
        {{ end }}
      {{ end }}
```

If you visit the link above, you will see it all works fine. However, the files currently output in ascending order, like so:

1. 2021-05-01.jpg
2. 2021-10-01.jpg
3. 2021-12-01.jpg

Ideally I would like them to output in descending order like so:

1. 2021-12-01.jpg
2. 2021-10-01.jpg
3. 2021-05-01.jpg

Is there any way I can achieve this with Hugo without resorting to renaming all my files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to the docs](https://gohugo.io/content-management/page-resources/#page-resources-metadata) it must be something like this:

```
{{ range sort (.Resources.ByType "image") "Name" "desc" }}
  ...
{{ end }}
```

I will test it later.

Comment: Yes that's it! Thanks so much for your help!